# Laravel 5.8 images appear as a broken square

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel 5.8 installed and an apache 2 server, it worked in previous servers, i moved the application to another server which i've done many times, except now something's wrong, images in the "storage/img" or other subdirectories within "storage" are not showing properly .. instead as a broken square.
The way i do it is like this:

```
Route::get('/assets/img/{name?}', [ function ($name = null) {
   if (is_null($name)) {
        abort(404);
    }
  
    $path = storage_path('img/'.$name) ;
    $mime_type = \App\Library\File::getFileType($path);

    if (\File::exists($path)) {
     return response()->file($path, array('Content-Type' => $mime_type));
    }
        abort(404);
}])->where('name', '.+');
```

So it picks the image from the storage folder and shows it to the public in the "assets/img" route, I applied the `php artisan storage:link` command just in case but nothing's working, I even tried to check if the file exists but yeah it did and so was its path.

[image: Broken image]

Comment: Did you check for error messages? My bet is that the image URL in your webpage returns a 404 or there's an error in the log you can use.

Comment: I checked logs and it returns a 200 status response, there is no error honestly, and when i download the image, it shows with its intended full size (here 180kb) but cannot be opened ... it's baffled since this morning

Comment: OK, so your code basically does work, more or less. You could inspect the image file itself, **from the output**, with a hex editor to see if there's anything at the beginning of the file stopping it from being displayed.

Comment: I checked the image code in the server and in the broken image on the browser, basically the same code (of course some characters show differently but it is the same).
I'm thinking to change how it works to simply put the images in the public folder directly or upload them by FTP to another server

Comment: Did you check the Content-Type returned?

Comment: Yup, it was image/png

Comment: Can you upload the broken image from the browser somewhere? There must be a logical explanation why that image file doesn't work. I would like to have a look myself.

Comment: the "corrupted - thumb.png" is the image that is shown on the browser, and the "thumb.png" is the original one in the server, i noticed the corrupted one starts with an empty line first, when i delete it = it works and the image shows in my computer when i open it with the picture viewer.

https://www.mediafire.com/view/isl7z8p6vb0i22c/thumb.png/file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/4ug5cjwnrm7r53n/corrupter+-+thumb.png/file

Comment: OMG I fixed it  it was an empty space in one of the php files I didn't even think about it till i used a command to search the server ... Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Ah, nice, problem solved. It's always the small things. 

Comment: Exactly :) now i wish i was a bigger problem to not feel this dumb 

Comment: Please be warned that Laravel 5.8 is EOL since nearly four years! You should start upgrading your application to any supported version

Comment: I've been busy with something else lately but i have been upgrading the staging now to Laravel 8 to make sure everything works so i can do it later in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by checking the php files of the server, I recently edited one but i left a space before <?php and that is adding a space to images' code.